# VirtualBox Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and exfat-fuse failing

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

(cannot move the question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43849858/virtualbox-ubuntu-16-04-lts-and-exfat-fuse-failing)

Ubuntu is apparently failing to correctly setup exFAT support after installing the `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` dependencies.

exFAT is nowhere listed on filesystems sources.
Any idea on what is going on? Am I missing something?

```
$ apt-cache policy exfat-fuse
exfat-fuse:
  Installed: 1.2.3-1
  Candidate: 1.2.3-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.3-1 500
        500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ apt-cache policy exfat-utils
exfat-utils:
  Installed: 1.2.3-1
  Candidate: 1.2.3-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.3-1 500
        500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ apt list --installed | egrep -i exfat

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

exfat-fuse/xenial,now 1.2.3-1 amd64 [installed]
exfat-utils/xenial,now 1.2.3-1 amd64 [installed]

$ cat /proc/filesystems | egrep -i exfat

$ mount -t (double tab)
adfs        bdev        cifs        davfs       ecryptfs    ext4        hfs         iso9660     mqueue      nfs4        proc        reiserfs    smbfs       sysv        udf         vboxsf
affs        bpf         coda        debugfs     efs         fuse        hfsplus     jffs2       msdos       ntfs        pstore      romfs       sockfs      tmpfs       ufs         vfat
auto        btrfs       cpuset      devpts      ext2        fuseblk     hpfs        jfs         ncpfs       ntfs-3g     qnx4        rootfs      squashfs    tracefs     umsdos      xfs
autofs      cgroup      cramfs      devtmpfs    ext3        fusectl     hugetlbfs   minix       nfs         pipefs      ramfs       securityfs  sysfs       ubifs       usbfs       

$ ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs
9p    afs      befs            btrfs       cifs      cramfs  exofs  freevxfs  gfs2     hpfs   jfs    ncpfs       nfsd    ntfs   overlayfs  qnx6      romfs  udf
adfs  aufs     bfs             cachefiles  coda      dlm     f2fs   fscache   hfs      isofs  lockd  nfs         nilfs2  ocfs2  pstore     quota     sysv   ufs
affs  autofs4  binfmt_misc.ko  ceph        configfs  efs     fat    fuse      hfsplus  jffs2  minix  nfs_common  nls     omfs   qnx4       reiserfs  ubifs  xfs

$ ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs | egrep -i exfat

$ sudo find / | egrep -i exfat
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/usr/share/doc/exfat-utils
/usr/share/doc/exfat-utils/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/exfat-utils/copyright
/usr/share/doc/exfat-fuse
/usr/share/doc/exfat-fuse/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/exfat-fuse/copyright
/usr/share/man/man8/exfatfsck.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/exfatlabel.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/mkexfatfs.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/dumpexfat.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/mount.exfat.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/mount.exfat-fuse.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/mkfs.exfat.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/fsck.exfat.8.gz
/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/exfat.mod
/var/lib/dpkg/info/exfat-utils.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/exfat-utils.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/exfat-fuse.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/exfat-fuse.list
/boot/grub/i386-pc/exfat.mod
/sbin/exfatlabel
/sbin/dumpexfat
/sbin/fsck.exfat
/sbin/mkfs.exfat
/sbin/mount.exfat
/sbin/mkexfatfs
/sbin/mount.exfat-fuse
/sbin/exfatfsck

$ sudo mount.exfat -o ro /mnt/aff/raw.000.raw /mnt/raw/
FUSE exfat 1.2.3
ERROR: exFAT file system is not found.

$ sudo mount.exfat-fuse -o ro /mnt/aff/raw.000.raw /mnt/raw/
FUSE exfat 1.2.3
ERROR: exFAT file system is not found.

$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu-VirtualBox 4.4.0-75-generic #96-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:56:33 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Edit**: Issue solved. Forgot to specify the volume offset (`mount -o offset=byteoffset`) in the image while mounting, which explains why the filesystem was not being found.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "*failing to correctly setup exFAT support*"? What actual issue are you trying to solve? I wouldn't expect `exfat-fuse` to provide kernel modules for example, since it's FUSE (filesystem in userspace)

Comment: @steeldriver The goal is to mount an exFAT filesystem volume from an image. Just trying to get that working on Ubuntu, since exFAT is not supported by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved. Forgot to specify the volume offset (`mount -o offset=byteoffset`) in the image while mounting, which explains why the filesystem was not being found.